# User input loop until they enter a number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a loop so that a question will keep appearing until a user correctly puts in a number. I've tried doing this, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh 

read -p "Welcome to the Draw Program. Please enter a number in-between 5-20: " input

while [ $input -lt 5 ] && [ $input -gt 20 ] 
do 
echo "Your number wasn't within the range. Please re-enter"
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can a number be simultaneously less than 5 **and** greater than 20?  I think you want:

```
while [ "$input" -lt 5 ] || [ "$input" -gt 20 ]
```

additionally you have to re-prompt for the number within the loop.

```
while [ "$input" -lt 5 ] || [ "$input" -gt 20 ]
do
    read -rp "Your number wasn't within the range. Please re-enter" input
done
```

---

As an FYI, the -p option for read is not specified by POSIX so it is not guaranteed to be supported on all forms of sh.  If this program is intended to be used across multiple obscure operating systems and portability is critical you can do something like:

```
printf '%s' "Your number wasn't within the range. Please re-enter: "
read -r input
```

Answer (score -1):

You might find it more intuitive and clearer to write:

```
while ! (( (5 <= input) && (input <= 20) )); do
    echo "Your number wasn't within the range. Please re-enter"
done
```

With the above you can see at a glance that it's testing for `input` being between `5` and `20` because that's where the variable name `input` sits in the code.